# Slow image slider on page load

Tags: image, performance, time, load, slider

Hi I hope someone can help -

I have just finished www.anormandygite.com and made it live. However when it loads there is a split second when the images stack before they loader into the slider.

Any suggestions as to how I can stop this?

Much appreciated, Kevin.

Comment: Please add some code or at least add the issue in fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Riskbreaker, oddly it does not happen on any site that I have developed with the same slider (such as www.george-dyke.co.uk)

Comment: Code coming head - <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  'slow',
        timeout: 7000,
        pager:  '#slider_nav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            // return sel string for existing anchor
            return '#slider_nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
        }
    });
});
</script>

Comment: How do I put a line break in this, enter just closes the comment?

Comment: I have figured it out, the tripadvisor ticker is slow the page down.

Comment: great glad you got it